# when using Aeron for Android

Tags: android, aeron

I create client Aeron on the Android app.
Unfortunately, Aeron is using Agrona which relies on `sun.misc.Unsafe`. Android don't support `sun.misc.Unsafe`.

Log error:

```
I/ientapplicatio: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.agrona.BufferUtil>: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field ARRAY_BYTE_BASE_OFFSET of type I in class Lsun/misc/Unsafe; or its superclasses (declaration of 'sun.misc.Unsafe' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at void org.agrona.UnsafeAccess.<clinit>() (UnsafeAccess.java:59)
        at void org.agrona.BufferUtil.<clinit>() (BufferUtil.java:47)
        at void org.agrona.BufferUtil.free(java.nio.ByteBuffer) (BufferUtil.java:241)
        at void io.aeron.Aeron$Context.close() (Aeron.java:1458)
        at void io.aeron.Aeron$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.close() ((null):-1)
        at void org.agrona.CloseHelper.quietClose(java.lang.AutoCloseable) (CloseHelper.java:41)
        at void io.aeron.Aeron.<init>(io.aeron.Aeron$Context) (Aeron.java:107)
        at io.aeron.Aeron io.aeron.Aeron.connect(io.aeron.Aeron$Context) (Aeron.java:139)
```

Hope someone can help me.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Aeron is not currently supported on Android.

Comment: Thank you so much @MichaelBarker.
Can I use C++ client or use Unsafe android wrapper?
https://github.com/iamironz/unsafe

Comment: You can try it, but we haven't tested or experimented with it, so your mileage may vary.